# flask query print all record table

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask

When i use this script in flask i'll print on the screen one record stored on my database only for 3 data :

```
app = Flask(__name__) 
@app.route("/")    
def index():    
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
     cur.execute('SELECT temperatura,umidita, orario FROM soggiorno ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;')
results = cur.fetchall()
    for row in results:
       temperatura = row[0]
       umidita = row[1]
       orario = row[2]
       return render_template('index.php',temperatura=temperatura,umidita=umidita , orario=orario)
    return render_template('index.html',templateData=rv)  


if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

My question is: how can you do a print for all record, in flask, stored on the database? And what to write for the part in html?

Comment: if you work your way through the flaskr tutorial you should have the answer to your question before you finish it....http://flask-.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/

Comment: Thank you.  if I had study the guide , I haven't written here

Answer (score 0):

In your sql remove `LIMIT 1` like so:

`cur.execute('SELECT temperatura,umidita, orario FROM soggiorno ORDER BY id DESC;')`